# refresh text box when a particular value is matched

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a text box in index.jsp and after writing something i am calling a jsp by jquery. But my requirement is if a particular value will be matched in server side then how can i auto refresh that text box? It means suppose i entered **apple** then by onkeyup event i am sending the name(apple) to check.jsp and in this jsp page, I have kept **apple** in a string. So now an alert will come in index.jsp that **apple** already exists and simulatenously that text box will be auto refreshed. How can i do it? I am a beginner to this field.

index.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#textbox").keyup(function () {
        $.getJSON('check.jsp', {
            textboxname: this.value
        });
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

inside body

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textboxname"/>
```

check.jsp

```
String textboxname=request.getParameter("textboxname");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on keyup send the value to the server and if it matches return true or false, then in the success handler check what is returned if its true refresh and not do something

```
$("#textbox").keyup(function () {
        $.getJSON('check.jsp', {
            textboxname: this.value
        },function(data){
          if(data.isTrue){
              alert("the value already exists");
              $("#textbox").val(''); //clear the text box                                  
         }
          else
              //do something                 
         });
    });
});
```

on the server *not the exact servlet code* but you'll get the idea

```
JSONObject match = new JSONObject();

 //if value matches 
     match.put("isTrue","true");
 else
    match.put("isTrue","false");
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(match.toString());true
```

Comment: ya it is working fine but how can i make an alert in client side that "sorry it already exists" and after 10 secs that alert will be vanished or if i will click "ok" button on that alert box then alert box will be vanished, how is it possible ?

Comment: you can do it in the `if` part where the value is being cleared show a div that contains the error message and use `setTimeout` of 10000 in which you will hide the error div

Comment: i was trying but error is coming can you please edit your code

Comment: if No problem then can you please edit your code so that i an alert box will come

Comment: thanks but please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340312/alert-box-in-css-inside-jquery) i have just asked a new question

Comment: ya but alert is coming 2 times that is  when data is present in the textbox then alert is coming and also after clearing that data alert is again coming

Comment: that is because you have attached a keyup event to it and when you will clear the data a key will be pressed and event will be fired

Comment: thanks for your answer but please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347654/combo-box-is-getting-vanished-when-an-alert-is-coming) please give me a suggestion