# alert box in css inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

I want to show an error alert box inside the `if block in jquery` but error is coming. Can anybody help me here. I have found alert box from [this website](http://csscody.com/demo/jquery-demo/custom-alert-boxes-using-jquery/80/) but in that case i have to click on Error Message Popup Alert to see the alert, but how can i add that Error Message Popup Alert alert inside my `jquery if part` so that without click that alert box will apear?

```
 $("#textbox").keyup(function () {
    $.getJSON('check.jsp', {
        textboxname: this.value
    },function(data){
      if(data.isTrue){
          $("#textbox").val(''); //clear the text box and show that Error Message Popup Alert
      }
      else{
       //do something 
      }             
     });
});
```

Comment: you can do it inside the if block what is the error you are getting

Comment: actually no alert box is appearing have you seen that website i have to click on Error Message Popup Alert alert to appear the alert but without any click it is not appearing

Comment: @3nigma any suggestion please

Comment: the answer by @Chamika Sandamal should solve your problem

Comment: i have posted an answer with the demo add the js files inside the head section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call it like following code,

```
$("#textbox").keyup(function () {
    $.getJSON('check.jsp', {
        textboxname: this.value
    },function(data){
      if(data.isTrue){
          $("#textbox").val(''); //clear the text box and show that Error Message Popup Alert
          csscody.alert(data);
      }
      else{
       //do something 
      }             
     });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you please add that Error Message Popup Alert(at 2nd position) from [this](http://csscody.com/demo/wp-content/demo/popup/demo.htm) website?

Comment: ok but what is this csscody? i have to write css coding in that function?

Comment: `csscody` is a JavaScript library. you don't need to do anything inside it. just add reference and call it. and if this solved your problem mark as answer.

Comment: you have to pass the data to the message. `data.someProperty`

Comment: ya it worked but after alert why some of other textboxes are being vanished? when i am refrshing that page then only these vanished textboxes are appearing. Any help please

Comment: without seeing whole code cannot guess what is the issue. can you post a separate question with the whole code or set the jsfiddle sample for the code

Comment: ok i am posting a new question, hope there i will get an answer

Comment: i have asked in a separate question please help me if possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347654/combo-box-is-getting-vanished-when-an-alert-is-coming

Answer (score 1):

```
if(data.isTrue){
    $("#textbox").val(''); //clear the text box and show that Error Message Popup Alert
    csscody.alert('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

include the following js files in your `HEAD` section

> http://csscody.com/demo/wp-content/demo/popup/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js
>
> http://csscody.com/demo/wp-content/demo/popup/js/alertbox.js
>
> http://csscody.com/demo/wp-content/demo/popup/js/style.css

then in the success handler inside the `if` block alert the message like

```
$("#textbox").keyup(function () {
    $.getJSON('check.jsp', {
        textboxname: this.value
    },function(data){
      if(data.isTrue){
           csscody.alert("user name already exists");
          $("#textbox").val(''); //clear the text box and show that Error Message Popup Alert

      }
      else{
       //do something 
      }             
     });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/U8NZk/128/)

Comment: ya i included all files in head section but still it is not working like that alert.

Comment: in your demo it working fine but in your above code i cannot find any success handler

Comment: AH! the function which you pass as the second argument of the `getJSON` function is called success handler

Comment: ya it worked but after alert why some of other textboxes are being vanished? Any help please

Comment: did you selected the text box by id ? then it means you are using idetical ids on the page which is a bad practice, ids have to be unique

Comment: i saw my entire jsp page but there is only one id textbox. Some modification is to be done in alert.js file i think, please any suggestion

Comment: ya i wrote your updated answer but same problem, before alert all text boxes and combo boxes are coming but after alert some combo boxes are going to be vanished. How can it be solved Any suggestion please

Comment: have asked in a separate question please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347654/combo-box-is-getting-vanished-when-an-alert-is-coming